# Can't create component as it has dependencies to be satisfied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, asp.net-boilerplate

I am learning DDD, n-Tier, Repositoriess and the likes. Someone pointed me to ASP.NET Boilerplate and I decided to start a test project using that. I have never dealt with dependency injection so this is all new to me, but the DI dependency it uses ius Castle Windsor. Now, I created a Model and from this Model I created an interface. I also added a Service. Whenever I fire up the app it gives me this error:

```
Can't create component 'TestApp.Services.MemberInfo.MemberAppService'
as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'TestApp.Services.MemberInfo.MemberAppService' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'TestApp.Repositories.IMemberInfoRepository' which was not registered.
```

I know you've got to register services and the likes, but reading ABPs documentation it says here, http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#DocAbpInfrastructure, that they are registered automatically if you add App to the name of the class. Basically, this is my code:

IMemberInfoRepository

```
    public interface IMemberInfoRepository : IRepository<MemberInfo, Guid>
{

}
```

MemberAppService

```
 public class MemberAppService : IMemberAppService
{
    private readonly Repositories.IMemberInfoRepository _memberInfoRepository;

    public MemberAppService(Repositories.IMemberInfoRepository memberInfoRepository)
    {
        _memberInfoRepository = memberInfoRepository;
    }

    public void Create(MemberInfoDto input)
    {
      _memberInfoRepository.Insert(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<m.MemberInfo>(input));
    }
```

IMemberAppService

```
public interface IMemberAppService :IApplicationService
{
    void Create(MemberInfoDto input);
}
```

So, here I am. Stuck. I read some Castle Windsor official documentation but as this is my first rodeo with this I am stuck at on what to do. Anything else would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The linked documentation suggests you should call `IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` "to [tell] ASP.NET Boilerplate to register your assembly by convention"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem but I could solve it!

This is a screenshot of the error given by IIS.

[image]

The reason of the error is that ABP cannot find the defined entity class `Member`.

The solution was to add the code `public virtual IDbSet<Members> Members { set; get; }`in the DbContext of the `EntityFramework` Project.

Answer (score 0):

after my workmate updated one ABP version, I met the same error. I checked my old code. found that, he missed to attach one cs file to the project. then I recoved it, now it works. please check whether you have similar file in the same path, wish it can help you.

[EF project]\EntityFramework\Repositories\xxxxRepository.cs

if you did not have, please create a similar one as xxxxRepositoryBase.cs